# What is a z/TPF system with respect to sockets?

Tags: linux, sockets

From here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSB23S_1.1.0.10/com.ibm.ztpf-ztpfdf.doc_put.10/gtps5/s5blanb.html?cp=SSB23S_1.1.0.10%2F0-1-8-2-5-0

> If an application places a TCP socket in nonblocking mode and issues a
>   read() socket function, 
>                     the ***z/TPF*** system will always return immediately to the application, either passing back the 
>                     requested data if it is in the receive buffer of the socket, or setting the return code to 
>                     indicate that no data is available.

**What is a z/TPF system with respect to sockets?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

z/TPF is a transaction processing facility on an IBM mainframe. If you aren't using a mainframe then this is irrelevant to you.

- [IBM product overview](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSB23S_1.1.0.10/com.ibm.ztpf-ztpfdf.doc_put.10/prod_z/czprodover.html)
- [Wikipedia entry on z/TPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transaction_Processing_Facility) with some historic background